# Issue to delete user via "invoke-sshcommand"

Tags: powershell

To delete an user, I have to enter the command `conf t` but this one is not taken into account

Bellow my script :

```
import-module SSH-Sessions
new-sshsession X.X.X.X -username xxxx -password xxxxx
Invoke-Sshcommand X.X.X.X -command 'conf t | no username yyyy'
```

Can you help me please ?

Comment: What is the relation with [tag:html5] here?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "html5" was a mistake. Sorry sorry sorry

Comment: Ok, doesn't matter :)